# How to convert a python list to pandas Dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this `python` `list` and I need to convert it into `pandas` `dataframe`.

This is how my list looks like:

```
thisdict = {}

thisdict["Column1"] = 1
thisdict["Column2"] = 2

thisdict # this print

{'Column1': 1, 'Column2': 2}
```

And I need to convert this to `pandas` dataframe.

I tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(thisdict)
```

and I got the error as below:

> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Can someone please help me?

Comment: How do you want your dataframe?  One row two columns or two rows one column?

Comment: Assign `1` and `2` as lists `thisdict["Column1"] = [1]` and `thisdict["Column2"] = [2]`

Comment: @ScottBoston I need `two` columns and `one` row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to assign the column as lists in your code.

Try replacing lines 2 and 3 with :

```py
thisdict["Column1"] = [1]
thisdict["Column2"] = [2]
```

Complete code :

```py
thisdict = {}
thisdict["Column1"] = [1]
thisdict["Column2"] = [2]
df = pd.DataFrame(thisdict)
```

Output :

```
    Column1 Column2
0         1       2
```

Comment: Do you know how can set columns to that data frame as well? So the column names are `Column1` and `Column2`

Comment: The column names are what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you didn't want to make your columns as lists, you could do this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(thisdict)).transpose()
```

Answer (score 1):

If your dictionary is going to one row of a dataframe you need to pass in a list with a single element.

```
pd.DataFrame(thisdict, index=[0])
```

Output:

```
   Column1  Column2
0        1        2
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question what you want, but here are a couple options; I think you probably want the second option. To achieve it, make sure you use a list when you build your dictionary.

**Option-1**

```
thisdict = {}
thisdict["Column1"] = 1
thisdict["Column2"] = 2
print(thisdict)

print("Below is Option1:")
df = pd.DataFrame(list(thisdict.items()),columns = ['ColumnA','ColumnB'])
display(df)
```

[image]

**Option-2**

```
thisdict = {}
thisdict["Column1"] = [1]
thisdict["Column2"] = [2]
print(thisdict)

print("Below is Option2:")
df = pd.DataFrame(thisdict)
display(df)
```

[image]

Comment: This is quite helpful. I needed the second option. Thank you